# How to add custom xinetd Service in pfSense

Tags: pfsense, xinetd

On a pfSense 2.4, I installed a custom xinetd service. I appended the necessary line to the list in `/etc/services` and wrote a stanza in `/var/etc/xinetd.conf`. After reloading xinetd, the service runs successfully.

However, the file `/var/etc/xinetd.conf` gets overwritten after some time automatically, and the stanza I wrote gets removed, and the service is being reloaded, and so my custom xinetd service disappears.

How can I make the changes to the xinetd configuration persistent?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The config file stored in `/var/etc/xinetd.conf` is regenerated every time you perform a filter reload.

To make changes to this process, you need to modify the filter reload process, you can find it on `/etc/inc/filter.inc`.

Start by creating a directory of xinetd config files that will be included at filter reload time:

```
 mkdir -p /opt/etc/xinetd.d
```

Create your custom xinetd config file inside that dir, e.g.: `/opt/etc/xinetd.d/custom.conf`

Open `/etc/inc/filter.inc` in your favourite editor and find the line which begins with `fclose($xinetd_fd);`

This is the last part of the xinetd.conf file generation function. Before that line add the `fwrite` line below, the end result should look like this:

```
    fwrite($xinetd_fd, "includedir /opt/etc/xinetd.d");
    fclose($xinetd_fd);             // Close file handle
```

Manually initiate a filter reload from `Status / Filter Reload / Reload Filters` and verify that custom.conf has been loaded as well.

Comment: That's it. I also wrote a cron job that ensures that the line `fwrite...` is prepended to `fclose` (maybe the php file gets modified on updates), and now it works.